# Custom skin for android libVLC

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, skin

I'm new to vlc lib and want to implement custom video player in my app with help of it. There is a common way to create skins for VLC on desktop, but I didn't find an example of doing so in android. What is the approach? Are there methods out of the box or should I just create my custom view with the corresponding listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the source code of VLC Android, I found out, that all gui is fully built as regular android custom views (see usages of `player_hud` in `player.xml` at [source code](http://git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/android.git))